# Finding a single quote after an equal sign in a string using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of strings formatted as follows:

value="hello"

The issue is that in some cases, there is no double quote after the equal sign (it may be a single quote or no quotes at all).

I am trying to add the double quote into the string.

I have tried the follow regex python code at regex101.com using the python mode:

```
import re

string1="value='hello''"
string1=string1.replace("''",'"')

regex = r'=[^\"]'

subst = '=\"'

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, string1, 0, re.MULTILINE)

print(result)

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```

I am expecting the result to print out as

```
"hello"
```

but I am getting

```
'hello"
```

Comment: Why not just remove single quotes`'`? `"'hello''".replace("'",'')`?

Comment: Ill be pulling values from the string based on the pattern r'\w*=\".*?\"'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a pattern that looks for a word surrounded in optional single quotes, and substitute it with the word in double quotes:

```
print(re.sub(r"(?<==)'*(\w+)'*", r'"\1"', "value='hello''"))
print(re.sub(r"(?<==)'*(\w+)'*", r'"\1"', "value=hello"))
```

This outputs:

```
value="hello"
value="hello"
```